# jQuery .animate() causing jumpy input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to animate the width of a `<div>` when a child `<input>` is focused. However, this is causing the input to jump up and down when the event is fired. It seems to be something with `inline-block`.

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5w3j2ro/)

### HTML

```
<div id="simp-inputs">
  <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="simp-date">Date: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="simp-date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="simp-start-time">Start Time: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="simp-start-time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="simp-end-time">End Time: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="simp-end-time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="simp-comments">Comments: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="simp-comments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label></label>
    <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="simp-submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#simp-inputs > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

#simp-inputs > div:last-child {
  width: auto;
}

#simp-submit {
  margin-top: 65px;
}

#simp-inputs input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var comments = $('#simp-comments');
comments.focusin(function() {
  var div = $(this).parent().parent();
  div.animate({
      width: '30vw'
    },
    300);
});
comments.focusout(function() {
  var div = $(this).parent().parent(),
    val = $(this).val();
  if (!val.length) {
    div.animate({
        width: '15vw'
      },
      300);
  }
});
```

Comment: During the animation, `overflow: hidden` gets added to the `div`. That seems to cause the layout issue. You can test this by adding `overflow:hidden` to the `div` manually... you should see the same result. I have no idea why 1) jQuery adds `overflow:hidden` during the animation, and 2) why that causes the layout issue you're seeing. (Sorry! But I hope this helps get you closer to finding the answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few small things working against you here that are causing this effect.

[**Working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f5w3j2ro/2/)

1) There is a `margin-top: 65px;` on your submit button and not the rest of your elements. This is the first reason you are experiencing the up-down jumping effect when the button drops below the other elements.

2) As mentioned by @smarx, jQuery is adding `overflow: hidden;` to your element while it animates as having a defined `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` can cause issues with the animations. This is jQuery's way of ensuring the animation remains smooth (ironic in this case) and is the second reason you are experiencing this. You can force an overflow on its container to ensure this does not happen with an `!important` tag.